# Код работает неправильно

Tags: java

Когда появляется окошко, там есть две JRadioButton. В зависимости от того, какая кнопка выбрана, переменной thing должно присваиваться значение true или false. Но вне зависимости от того, какую кнопку я нажимаю, lol оказывается равно false. В чем дело?

```
public class tnn extends JDialog {

private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
public boolean lol;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */

/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public tnn(erer owner) {

    super(owner, true);
    setTitle("\u041D\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0440\u043E\u0439\u043A\u0438");
    setBounds(100, 100, 377, 356);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPanel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("\u041A\u0435\u043C \u0431\u0443\u0434\u0435\u0442\u0435 \u0438\u0433\u0440\u0430\u0442\u044C?");
    label.setBounds(109, 22, 123, 28);
    contentPanel.add(label);

    JRadioButton krestik = new JRadioButton("\u0422\u0430\u0439\u0445\u044D\u0439");

    buttonGroup.add(krestik);
    krestik.setBounds(54, 64, 109, 23);
    contentPanel.add(krestik);

    JRadioButton nolik = new JRadioButton("\u0423\u043C\u0430\u0440\u0443");

    buttonGroup.add(nolik);
    nolik.setBounds(211, 64, 109, 23);
    contentPanel.add(nolik);

    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("");
    label_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(tnn.class.getResource("/images/10.png")));
    label_1.setBounds(36, 104, 99, 147);
    contentPanel.add(label_1);

    JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("");
    label_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(tnn.class.getResource("/images/20.png")));
    label_2.setBounds(196, 123, 99, 117);
    contentPanel.add(label_2);

    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
    buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(krestik.isSelected()){
                lol = true;
            } else lol = false;

            setVisible(false);
            dispose();
        }
    });
            okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
            buttonPane.add(okButton);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);

        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("\u041E\u0442\u043C\u0435\u043D\u0430");
        cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();
            }
        });
            cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
            buttonPane.add(cancelButton);

}

public boolean isLol() {
    return lol;
}
```

}

Comment: Поставить 2 брейкпоинта и проверить, не?

Comment: Больше похоже на декомпил